# I have JSON data and I would like to show that on Full Calender

Tags: javascript, json

```
function getMTPForCalendar(){
    var data=$('#mtp-form').serialize();  
    $.ajax({
            type :'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
             url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/mtp/mtpForCalendar",

            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                var eventData=[];

                alert(JSON.stringify(data))
                 for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){ 
                 var source = { events:[
                                        {
                                            title: data[i]['doctorName'],
                                            start: data[i]['plannedDate']
                                        }
                            ]};
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', source );

                }

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {

            }

    });
```

the values are coming but the problem is that only 1 event value generated..and after again search the same value arises on that particular date..I think Loop is not proper working..Give me the Appropriate code..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEvent', event ) rather than $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', source ), or you set up all events in the source, then addEventSource after the for loop.